# Caching a control on a JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, caching, controls

I have a control on a javascript page. I can access this by id, but what I want to do is cache the control since I'm referencing it in a few places. How can I cache this control with say an id=TestControl

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable<sup>1</sup> and safe a reference to the element (control) in it:

```
var testControl = document.getElementById("TestControl");
```

Ensure ou run that code *after* the element has been created (for instance, put the `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag).

If you do that at the top level of your code, for instance:

```
// Scoping function to avoid creating globals
(function() {
    var testControl = document.getElementById("TestControl");

    // Your code here

})();
```

...all of your code will have access to the variable.

---

<sup>1</sup> *In fact, the browser has already done that for you by creating an* automatic global *called `TestControl`, but I never advocate using automatic globals. The global namespace is just too crowded, too easy to get bitten by conflicts.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that code needed to go in a $(document).ready() function. I was trying to reference it before the document loaded. Thank you for your very fast response!